# Individual column searching (text inputs)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an individual search box for each table column without success. 
What should be added to code below in order to make it work?

Currently my code contains a single search box for first column only.

Please run snippet to get full details.

[image]

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
p.a {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    h2 {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    table {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left;
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 90%;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
    table tbody tr:hover {
        background-color: #dddddd;
    }
    .wide {
        width: 90%;
    }
```

```html
   <h2> Title here </h2>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name"><table border="1" class="dataframe wide" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>KEY</th>
      <th>DEVREVSTEP</th>
      <th>WW32</th>
      <th>WW33</th>
      <th>WW34</th>
      <th>WW35</th>
      <th>WW36</th>
      <th>WW37</th>
      <th>WW38</th>
      <th>WW39</th>
      <th>WW40</th>
      <th>Rule</th>
      <th>LINK</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>-0.64</td>
      <td>6.47</td>
      <td>23.14</td>
      <td>3.51</td>
      <td>0.13</td>
      <td>-0.41</td>
      <td>-0.59</td>
      <td>-0.31</td>
      <td>33.13</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>Google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>Second</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>-18.04</td>
      <td>-18.42</td>
      <td>-17.44</td>
      <td>-16.35</td>
      <td>-19.06</td>
      <td>-17.49</td>
      <td>-18.62</td>
      <td>-17.92</td>
      <td>-18.23</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>Amazon.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>Third</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>-0.59</td>
      <td>2.25</td>
      <td>-0.33</td>
      <td>0.55</td>
      <td>-0.53</td>
      <td>8.96</td>
      <td>17.53</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>Ebay.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>Fourth</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>-0.18</td>
      <td>3.25</td>
      <td>7.63</td>
      <td>1.90</td>
      <td>-0.19</td>
      <td>0.41</td>
      <td>0.15</td>
      <td>0.20</td>
      <td>17.31</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>Yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td>Fourth</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>0.24</td>
      <td>-3.25</td>
      <td>-6.42</td>
      <td>-1.51</td>
      <td>0.60</td>
      <td>-0.01</td>
      <td>0.25</td>
      <td>-0.02</td>
      <td>-15.13</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>MSN.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>5</th>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>5.06</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>1.27</td>
      <td>-0.56</td>
      <td>13.24</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>Google.com</td>
    </tr>
    
   
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I works fine, add text boxes for other columns as well.

Comment: @its4zahoor That's my problem.  Can't manage to do that correctly.

Comment: Do you only want to see rows that have a match in all columns that you entered a filter/search value for, or if filter 1 matches row A and filter 2 on a different column matches row B, you still want to see both of them?

Comment: @04FS
Good point. I want to see rows that match conditions entered for all columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show only rows that are a match for all entered filter values - then you best loop over all the input fields on each change, that is easiest to handle.

I inserted input fields into the table header cells here, and then simply select them using `getElementsByTagName` - you can change that to a different position and / or using a different method to select them (f.e. by class maybe), it might need some slight adaptations then.

Notice how in both loops I start with the index 1 here, not 0 - to ignore the first table row in the `i` loop (because the header row should not disappear; could be done differently by selecting only the rows in the tbody to begin with), and to ignore the first cell in the `j` loop. And since the number of input fields is one less than the number of cells per row, I access the input using index `j - 1`, got get the one corresponding to the cell index.

This probably leaves room for refinements in several places, but should be enough to illustrate the basic principle.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var inputs, table, tr, i, j, inputValue, txtValue, showRow;
  inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
    showRow = true;
    for (j = 1; j < tr[i].cells.length; j++) {
      inputValue = inputs[j - 1].value
      txtValue = tr[i].cells[j].textContent || tr[i].cells[j].innerText;
      if (inputValue != "" && txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(inputValue.toUpperCase()) == -1) {
        showRow = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    tr[i].style.display = showRow ? "" : "none";
  }
}
```

```css
p.a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 90%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.wide {
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<h2> Title here </h2>
<table border="1" class="dataframe wide" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>KEY</th>
      <th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>DEVREVSTEP</th>
      <th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>WW32</th>
      <th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>WW33</th>
      <th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>WW34</th>
      <th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>WW35</th>
      <th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>WW36</th>
      <th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>WW37</th>
      <th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>WW38</th>
      <th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>WW39</th>
      <th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>WW40</th>
      <th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>Rule</th>
      <th><input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>LINK</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>-0.64</td>
      <td>6.47</td>
      <td>23.14</td>
      <td>3.51</td>
      <td>0.13</td>
      <td>-0.41</td>
      <td>-0.59</td>
      <td>-0.31</td>
      <td>33.13</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>Google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>Second</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>-18.04</td>
      <td>-18.42</td>
      <td>-17.44</td>
      <td>-16.35</td>
      <td>-19.06</td>
      <td>-17.49</td>
      <td>-18.62</td>
      <td>-17.92</td>
      <td>-18.23</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>Amazon.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>Third</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>-0.59</td>
      <td>2.25</td>
      <td>-0.33</td>
      <td>0.55</td>
      <td>-0.53</td>
      <td>8.96</td>
      <td>17.53</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>Ebay.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>Fourth</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>-0.18</td>
      <td>3.25</td>
      <td>7.63</td>
      <td>1.90</td>
      <td>-0.19</td>
      <td>0.41</td>
      <td>0.15</td>
      <td>0.20</td>
      <td>17.31</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>Yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td>Fourth</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>0.24</td>
      <td>-3.25</td>
      <td>-6.42</td>
      <td>-1.51</td>
      <td>0.60</td>
      <td>-0.01</td>
      <td>0.25</td>
      <td>-0.02</td>
      <td>-15.13</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>MSN.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>5</th>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>5.06</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>1.27</td>
      <td>-0.56</td>
      <td>13.24</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>Google.com</td>
    </tr>



  </tbody>
</table>
```